# Brute force evidence of possible proof of twin prime conjecture

Tags: prime-numbers

Trying to avoid shelling out hundreds of dollars so I'm using what I can for free online. This is what I've come up with so far:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76769933/TwinPrimes%203Podd.cdf

Trying to use this to demonstrate a possible way to prove the twin prime conjecture:

For every prime $p$ greater than 2, there exists one or more twin primes as follows:
$(3pn-4, 3pn-2)$ where $n$ is some positive odd less than or equal to $p$.

With the free version, I can only go so far.

My questions are these:

1. Would someone help test for a counter-example. Maybe refine this code to only print if a counter-example exists in the first million or so primes.
2. Would someone perhaps plot `Length[twin]` vs. $p$ to show that as $p$ increases, so does the number of twins found.

I realize this question requires simultaneously a lot of knowledge of primes and Mathematica, as well as requiring you to look through code to fully understand the question, so thanks in advance.

Comment: Just messed with this some. Found this: as $p$ increases, so does the number of twin primes. I've also found that it is **highly** unlikely a counter-example will be found. The highest % through odds before a twin prime is found is 78%; the next highest being only 40%, with the average percent dropping heavily as $p$ increases. The proof of the twin prime conjecture is right here in the math; a nugget waiting to be dug up by someone who simply understands what's going on.

Comment: If this result is original, it is extremely impressive and paper-worthy. I do wonder, however, if it's an already known result. In either case, I suggest keeping this question open.

Comment: @barrycarter Not to be contrarian, but what is surprising about finding twin primes in this way? I would think the surprise would be if one did not find them. The "expected value" (based on PNT as giving a "probability") looks like it is increasing as a function of prime `p`.

Comment: @barrycarter Okay, yeah, I am being contrarian.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau If the OP has found a way to generate an infinite number of twin primes, this is noteworthy. I realize it requires a larger number of steps as $p$ increases, but the fact that it's a *finite* number of steps for each $p$ seems remarkable.

Comment: @BarryCarter I am unconvinced. Suppose I give you a subset range of n in which to look for primes `p`; for a sufficiently "thick" subset, one might expect that there will be cases where `2n-p` is also prime. That is, we find Goldbach pairs in some restricted subset. Would this be a surprise? My answer: it depends on how thick that subset is, relative to the probability that `2n-p` is prime.

Comment: Minor unrelated note: try to turn this into 3*n*p+-1 since that looks "cleaner" and might make it easier to find existing works. Also, I must ask: aside from wolframalpha.com (which I don't think will do what you're doing), what free version of Mathematica is their online? Are you using a free trial of webMathematica or something?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau About you being contrarian, that's pretty much why I asked this here. Looking for some reason this should be ignored, whether counter-example, or reason this would not prove the twin prime conjecture. Check the (yet unanswered, low-voted) thoughts out here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1677373/would-this-be-an-easier-way-to-prove-the-twin-prime-conjecture .

Comment: @DanielLichtblau About "I am not convinced," where this is amazing, is that for every prime (which have been proven to be infinite), there exists at least one **unique** twin prime (which is only **conjectured** to be infinite). This uniqueness is easily provable even by me, a simple elementary math teacher with only a bachelor's math ed degree. I just can't yet prove each prime yields a twin prime... just strongly indicate.

Comment: @barrycarter Thanks for your interest! To my knowledge, this is original. Here's my path of discovery: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76769933/Twin%20discoveries.txt .

Comment: @DanielLichtblau One more thought on "I am unconvinced," try tho infinite rule-guided subsets with each subset **always** containing one or more **unique** twin primes and **none** in any more than one subset. That's where this has merit.

Comment: @barrycarter About minor note, using 2 and 4 has its purpose as explained in my path to discovery. +-1 may have "empty buckets." Thanks for the thought tho. I'm using an expired trial on mathematica.wolframcloud.com/app that has memory and time limits, as well as the Wolfram Alpha app for android. Might eventually by a raspberry pi just to get full Mathematica free, although the speed wouldn't be great I suppose. "Your Wolfram Mathematica Online trial expired on March 01, 2016. Cloud Storage : 0.03 GB. File Size Limit : 10 MB. Session Memory : 512 MB. Computation Length : 300 seconds."

Comment: I get worried when I see phrases such as "one or more unique xxx". It's just not clear what that means.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Which is the unclear part? "One or more" or "unique"? Let me know and I'll clarify.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Looking at my answer to my own question, {2,1} from "Out(44)" means the second prime, 3, creates 1 twin prime, (5,7). The third creates 3, and the 4000th creates 319, or "One or more." These 319 are also "unique" in that they cannot be created by any previous prime. Hope that removes ambiguity.

Comment: (1) For any prime `n`, the expected cound is something like this. There is a constant `k` (independent of `n`) for which it should be approximated as `k*Integrate[1/n*1/Log[j]^2, {j, 3 n, 3 n^2}, Assumptions -> n > 2]`. The problem I have is this. Integrate[1/n*1/Log[j]^2, {j, 3 n, 3 n^2}, Assumptions -> n > 2];My reasoning suggests `k` should be 3/2, but numeric computation strongly suggests it is actually 4/3. So there is a discrepancy somewhere. On the bright side, that integral does indeed closely track the count to within a constant factor (again, probably 4/3).

Comment: (2) One can more readily get the counts as below. This may take a few minutes to get through the topmost power of 10 though. `In[237]:= actualcounts = Table[p = Prime[PrimePi[10^k]];
  twinprimeC = 0;
  Do[If[PrimeQ[3*p*j - 4] && PrimeQ[3*p*j - 2], twinprimeC++],
   {j, 1, p, 2}];
  twinprimeC, {k, 1, 8}]

Out[237]= {3, 5, 25, 114, 760, 5133, 38155, 290499}`.

Comment: (3) I do not much like the subject header. This is not a proof of anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No counterexample.

```
ClearAll[p]
p = 2;
primes = Reap[While[p <= 1000000, Sow[p = NextPrime[p]]]][[2, 1]];

Do[
  Table[
   If[PrimeQ[3*primes[[i]]*j - 4 (* or 2 *)],
    Continue[]
    ]
   ,
   {j, 1, primes[[i]], 2}
   ];
  Return[i]
  ,
  {i, 1, Length@primes}
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {76.1693, Null}

```
twinPrimes = Table[
   {
    primes[[i]],
    Pick[#, PrimeQ@#, True] &@(3*primes[[i]]*Cases[Range@primes[[i]], _?OddQ] - 4),
    Pick[#, PrimeQ@#, True] &@(3*primes[[i]]*Cases[Range@primes[[i]], _?OddQ] - 2)
    },
   {i, 10}
   ];

twinPrimes // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[
 {
  {#[[1]], Length@#[[2]]} & /@ twinPrimes,
  {#[[1]], Length@#[[3]]} & /@ twinPrimes
  },
 AxesLabel -> {"prime number", "twins amount"},
 ImageSize -> Large
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Technically, aren't these the primes under one million and not the first one million primes?

Comment: @barrycarter You are correct. These are primes under 1M (around 79K primes). Maybe later I will check more primes.

Comment: True, but still, awesome work! Thanks for not ignoring a question on hold! As I commented on the original question, the indication is strong that no counter-example will be found. Maybe a graphic plot like my 2nd question would help show this?

Comment: @user3363795 Updated. Plot of the first 2K twinPrimes.

Comment: That plot is sick! I knew this was convincing evidence of the twin prime conjecture, but that is awesome! It appears nearly linear!

Comment: One thing I don't get... your results for twin prime table show numbers without a twin prime pair, like 23. Is your plot only counting numbers such that **both** $3pn-4$ and $3pn-2$ are simultaneously prime for the same $pn$?

Comment: @user3363795 Not both. Blue line is $3pn-4$ and orange is $3pn-2$.

Comment: Ah, any way to plot when both are prime simultaneously? Maybe something like (column 3) - 2 having same element as (column 2)?

Comment: @user3363795 $3pn-4$ and $3pn-2$ have no common primes. `MapThread[Length@Intersection[#1,#2]&,{twinPrimes[[;;,2]],twinPrimes[[;;,3]]}]//Tally` Output: `{{0, 2000}}`

Comment: @Alexey I ran with your ideas and worked up something to show you what I mean down below. This allows q through if and only if both q-4 and q-2 are simultaneously prime, and thus a twin prime. From your chart, for 3, {5,7} is let through as a twin prime whereas {23} doesn't have a pair. This is shown in my graph as the 2nd prime, 3, creates only one twin.

Comment: I cannot figure out what it is being shown in that table.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I found I can go a little further on lab.wolframcloud.com/app. Here's what I've done with a lot of ideas from @Alexey Golyshev.

[Updated 3/29 18:21]
Download and run this notebook: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76769933/Twinprimeplotting.nb

to get this:
[image: ![enter image description here]

Don't know how much further I can go with this. Need someone to stand on my shoulders and take this further!

Comment: Added best fit line and parabola. That parabola is so close to a line, there must be something going on here. I may post this on math.stackexchange just to see if someone can explain why this line holds so well.

Comment: "so close to a line" - did you have a look at the coefficient of determination?

Comment: This might be better asymptotically: `In[43]:= curve = FindFit[data, x/(b*Log[x])^2, {b}, x];
new = x/(b*Log[x])^2 /. curve

Out[44]= (5.45108297312 x)/Log[x]^2`

Comment: To understand where that suggested fit arose, take a series at infinity of the integral estimate I put in a comment under the original post.

Comment: @J.M. Sorry, elem. math teacher with only a Bach. degree. Define "coefficient of determination", and how I would find it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not even a mathematician or a statistician. But you may be familiar with $R^2$; you can use `LinearModelFit[]` to generate that.

Comment: @J.M. Fit[] was used which should have given least squares regression if I understand right. Just not sure what a coefficient of determination is, or how to find it.

Comment: It was an oblique nudge to look at the docs for `LinearModelFit[]`; in particular. `"RSquared"`.

Comment: K, I think I figured it out. "Coefficient of determination" **is** $R^2$, or how good the least squares regression line is and can only be found using LinearModelFit, not just fit. Linear is 0.9214, parabolic is 0.9228 for the data range of 60 to 800. Close to 1 and similar would indicate a good fit as well as parabolic providing nearly negligible advantage over linear.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Mind helping with the "series at infinity of the integral estimate"? Teaching 4th grade too long, my calc is rusty.

Comment: `In[1334]:= ii = 
 Integrate[1/n*1/Log[j]^2, {j, 3 n, 3 n^2}, Assumptions -> n > 2]
iiser = Expand[
  Normal[Series[ii, {n, Infinity, 1}, Assumptions -> n > 1000]]]

Out[1334]= (
3 n (1/Log[3 n] - n/Log[3 n^2]) - LogIntegral[3 n] + 
 LogIntegral[3 n^2])/n` The result is too long for a comment. The "main" contribution is from the term in `n` with denominator that increases slowest, which involves a `Log[n]^2+constant`.